# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'early_stopping_rounds' for CatBoost in Python

Tags: python, catboost

I get this error when I try to run a CatBoost algorithm. It is one of the parameters so I don't understand why this error occurs when I comment out early_stopping_rounds I get the same error for cat_features parameter

```py
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier

categorical_indexes = np.where(X.dtypes == 'object')[0]
X.drop(["id"], axis = 1, inplace = True)

params = {'loss_function':'Logloss', 
          'eval_metric':'AUC', 
          'verbose': 200, 
          "early_stopping_rounds": 200,
          "cat_features": categorical_indexes,
          'random_seed': 17}
cat = CatBoostClassifier(**params)
cat.fit(X,y)
```

---

**Edit:**
Upgraded catboost package via pip now I am getting another error
However, in my code I'm filtering categorical values then assigning to them to cat_features parameter

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
_catboost.pyx in _catboost.get_float_feature()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._FloatOrNan()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._FloatOrNanFromString()

TypeError: Cannot convert 'b'Triangle'' to float

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

CatBoostError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1190699fd260> in <module>
     74 
     75 cat = CatBoostClassifier(loss_function='Logloss', eval_metric='AUC', verbose=200, early_stopping_rounds=200, cat_features=np.array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20]), random_seed=17)
---> 76 cat.fit(X,y)
     77 
     78 

c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in fit(self, X, y, cat_features, text_features, sample_weight, baseline, use_best_model, eval_set, verbose, logging_level, plot, column_description, verbose_eval, metric_period, silent, early_stopping_rounds, save_snapshot, snapshot_file, snapshot_interval, init_model)
   3786         self._fit(X, y, cat_features, text_features, None, sample_weight, None, None, None, None, baseline, use_best_model,
   3787                   eval_set, verbose, logging_level, plot, column_description, verbose_eval, metric_period,
-> 3788                   silent, early_stopping_rounds, save_snapshot, snapshot_file, snapshot_interval, init_model)
   3789         return self
   3790 

c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in _fit(self, X, y, cat_features, text_features, pairs, sample_weight, group_id, group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, use_best_model, eval_set, verbose, logging_level, plot, column_description, verbose_eval, metric_period, silent, early_stopping_rounds, save_snapshot, snapshot_file, snapshot_interval, init_model)
   1670             use_best_model, eval_set, verbose, logging_level, plot,
   1671             column_description, verbose_eval, metric_period, silent, early_stopping_rounds,
-> 1672             save_snapshot, snapshot_file, snapshot_interval, init_model
   1673         )
   1674         params = train_params["params"]

c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in _prepare_train_params(self, X, y, cat_features, text_features, pairs, sample_weight, group_id, group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, use_best_model, eval_set, verbose, logging_level, plot, column_description, verbose_eval, metric_period, silent, early_stopping_rounds, save_snapshot, snapshot_file, snapshot_interval, init_model)
   1558 
   1559         train_pool = _build_train_pool(X, y, cat_features, text_features, pairs, sample_weight, group_id,
-> 1560                                        group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, column_description)
   1561         if train_pool.is_empty_:
   1562             raise CatBoostError("X is empty.")

c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in _build_train_pool(X, y, cat_features, text_features, pairs, sample_weight, group_id, group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, column_description)
    968             raise CatBoostError("y has not initialized in fit(): X is not catboost.Pool object, y must be not None in fit().")
    969         train_pool = Pool(X, y, cat_features=cat_features, text_features=text_features, pairs=pairs, weight=sample_weight, group_id=group_id,
--> 970                           group_weight=group_weight, subgroup_id=subgroup_id, pairs_weight=pairs_weight, baseline=baseline)
    971     return train_pool
    972 

c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in __init__(self, data, label, cat_features, text_features, column_description, pairs, delimiter, has_header, weight, group_id, group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, feature_names, thread_count)
    369                         )
    370 
--> 371                 self._init(data, label, cat_features, text_features, pairs, weight, group_id, group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, feature_names)
    372         super(Pool, self).__init__()
    373 

c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in _init(self, data, label, cat_features, text_features, pairs, weight, group_id, group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, feature_names)
    949             baseline = np.reshape(baseline, (samples_count, -1))
    950             self._check_baseline_shape(baseline, samples_count)
--> 951         self._init_pool(data, label, cat_features, text_features, pairs, weight, group_id, group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, feature_names)
    952 
    953 

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._PoolBase._init_pool()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._PoolBase._init_pool()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._PoolBase._init_features_order_layout_pool()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._set_features_order_data_pd_data_frame()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost.create_num_factor_data()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost.get_float_feature()

CatBoostError: Bad value for num_feature[non_default_doc_idx=0,feature_idx=5]="Triangle": Cannot convert 'b'Triangle'' to float
```

Comment: Can you post your `CatBoostClassifier` class? I'm guessing your class doesn't have an `early_stopping_rounds` or `cat_features` parameter in its constructor.

Comment: @mario_sunny how to find CatBoostClassifier class?

Comment: According to the doc these are valid parameters: https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostclassifier.html
Kind of a weird coincidence that the only two that are failing are double-quoted, even though that shouldn't matter.  What if you just call `cat = CatBoostClassifier(loss_function='Logloss', eval_metric='AUC', verbose=200, early_stopping_rounds=200, cat_features=categorical_indexes, random_seed=17)` instead of building a dict and passing it via **kwargs?

Comment: @SamStafford tried your way passed parameters directly to CatBoostClassifier. Still getting the same error

Comment: What version of CatBoost python library are you using? You should be able to run `import catboost; print(catboost.__version__)`

Comment: @ChrisZacharias I upgraded catboost via pip and now I'm getting a different error can you check it out?

Comment: Please post the full `traceback` into your post

Comment: @SyntaxVoid do you mean the error message as the one in the title ?

Comment: I mean the full traceback that appears when your program crashes. You edited your post to include the `CatBoostError` message, but the full traceback will include line number and a call-trace for each function called that led up to that exception. Knowing that information is very helpful, especially to people on stackoverflow who aren't as familiar with the library you are using. We can then use the traceback to *trace* how code *you* wrote eventually leads to the exception raised in the external library and can start thinking about how to fix it.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid thank you very clear, I edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you missed to specify the feature index or feature name for the categorical feature at "feature_idx=5" with value “Triangle”. Catboost tried to convert that binary string value to `float` and got the `CatBoostError`.

You can update that categorical feature indice or name  to your variable `categorical_indexes` when you construct the class `CatBoostClassifier`, or you can provide the list of categorical feature indices or names to argument `cat_features` of `fit()`

Comment: but I equate all categorical values to "categorical_indexes" in my code. Why does that not do the trick ?

Comment: it’s better to use colume feature names instead of indices. since you remove the ‘id’ from dataframe, the indice values in new frame are changed that make the mess. i always use the feature names instead of indices

Comment: when I pass in feature names to cat_features parameter it can I directly do that ? Like {..,cat_features = ["feature_1","feature_2"]...}

Comment: Yes, as you can see from CatBoostClassifier docs: 
`cat_features : list or numpy.array, [default=None]
        If not None, giving the list of Categ features indices or names (names are represented as strings).
        If it contains feature names, feature names must be defined for the training dataset passed to 'fit'.
`

Answer (score 0):

I Just tried checking of this parameter ('sampling_frequency') exists from official catboost algorithm page and seems like this has now been removed https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboost_fit.html#python-reference_catboost_fit__parameters

Answer (score 0):

I gave [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68505927/catboostregressor-is-showing-an-error-when-trying-to-predict-typeerror-cannot/69935911#69935911) here regarding capturing all your object variables to avoid this error while dev'ing with catboost.

```
# Get all object variables from X_train
cat_vars = [var for var in X_train.columns if X_train[var].dtype == "O"]

# Initialize model with cat_vars
rf = CatBoostClassifier(
               cat_features = cat_vars,
               eval_metric="RMSE",
               learning_rate=0.13,
               iterations=500,
               )
# Fit & Predict
rf.fit(X_train, y_train, plot=True, eval_set=(X_test, y_test))
pred_rf = rf.predict(X_test)
```